Why use coordinate-wise random rounding instead of regular rounding?
I've been reading a blog article on CKKS encoding and there they implement a coordinate-wise random rounding algorithm (which can be found in this paper) instead of the plain old rounding. The same algorithm is mentioned in the original CKKS paper too in section in 3.2. What is the reason for this? Why not just round off with the regular if statement.

So far I have come up with the following reasoning based on the famous paper "A Toolkit for Ring-LWE Cryptography" [1]:
When we discreticize the element $x$ with regular rounding, the error $e=x-\lfloor x \rceil$ depends on $x$. This makes it hard to prove the security features of the LWE problem still hold after rounding. It says in that paper that "Note that for a valid discretization, $\lfloor z+x \rceil_{\Lambda+c}$ and $z + \lfloor x \rceil_{\Lambda+c}$ are identically distributed for any $z\in \Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice. Then they continue to give three examples of rounding that are valid. The first (and perhaps the simplest) of these is the randomized rounding. Since we have $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{randround}(x)] = x$, this allows us to conclude that the distribution for the decimal part which is already bounded by 1 is $0$-subgaussian with parameter $\sqrt{2\pi}$. Then by a corollary in part 2.3 we get the validity of the rounding.
[1]: Lyubashevsky, V., Peikert, C., & Regev, O. (2013). A Toolkit for Ring-LWE Cryptography. Cryptology ePrint Archive, Paper 2013/293. https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/293
